# Could not find aaptcompiler-4.0.0.jar

Tags: android, android-studio

In android studio when I want to compile my app, it fails with this problem ( using android studio 4.0 )

```
Could not find aaptcompiler-4.0.0.jar (com.android.tools.build:aaptcompiler:4.0.0).
Searched in the following locations:
    https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aaptcompiler/4.0.0/aaptcompiler-4.0.0.jar
```

while I can open the link in browser and file in server really exists. ( I have added google() as repository )

Comment: I know it may sound stupid, but I always fix these kinds of issues by cleaning the project and building it again.

Comment: I did it, but not working